# Getting error in Program.cs per HttpClient

Tags: blazor, httpclient, dbcontext

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: <name of my service) Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: "Name of my service": Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'Name of my service'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: "Name of my service" Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: "Name of my service": Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate (Name of my service).)'

I tried adding:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpService>();
```

to my program.cs file. Without this, I cant load data. I seem to be getting closer to getting my services registered but I keep getting error above. Here is what my registration of services currently look like:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceName>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceName, ServiceName>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
```

Comment: Have you tried builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();  You may also want to read up on IHttpClientFactory for creating clients, to avoid socket exhaustion.  You could also register a named client, if that's suitable to your situation: builder.Services.AddHttpClient("currentWeather", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://...");
});

Comment: WASM or Server?